# Spring boot connect to docker service mongodb

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-data-mongodb

my spring boot application connected with mongo db.
here is the configs:

```
spring.mongodb.embedded.storage.repl-set-name=mongo
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongo
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

it works fine, but I want to create mongo replicas using docker service, like this:

```
 docker service create --name mongo --replicas=3 mongo
```

here is my mongo service

```
53cf3b73a510        mongo:latest        "docker-entrypoint..."   23 seconds ago      Up 23 seconds       27017/tcp                mongo.3.i5yvbe0mo0d2x83j2xf9ubvnv
54c9a5dbb93a        mongo:latest        "docker-entrypoint..."   24 seconds ago      Up 23 seconds       27017/tcp                mongo.1.rlqtw055adklfr4jqn8uete94
a6b78191b0e3        mongo:latest        "docker-entrypoint..."   24 seconds ago      Up 23 seconds       27017/tcp                mongo.2.52ha34l414k1k8xgndkkzm25m
```

So after this my connection to mongodb does not work.
I do not want use IP address.

I am using docker-compose and docker network.
https://github.com/armdev/docker-mongo-service/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

This is also does not work

```
org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongo.2:27017
    spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo.1:27017,mongo.2:27017/guruDB?replicaSet=mc
```